# Loading json files in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a dataset containing 1000 json files. I want to use Postgres and dump these files in the postgres table. Can someone suggest me what is the procedure for this.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 so I don't have the native `json` data type.

Comment: What's the MySQL tag for? *confused*. Any chance of providing some more detail? What client language are you using? what's generating the json? What do you expect to *do* with the json? how is this any different to loading a bunch of text files?

Comment: Sorry for the Mysql tag. I have a bunch of data files which are json. I want to dump them in Postgres and do some analysis on them. I tried using Apache Hive, but it takes a lot of time to process (according to my boss)

Comment: OK, so you don't want to load json into fields in PostgreSQL, you want to import JSON-structured data into PostgreSQL tables as individual fields for analysis. Right? If so: Show some example data, describe the data. It is fairly uniform in structure? Frankly I recommend looking into ETL tools - Talend Studio, CloverETL, or Pentaho Kettle. Or just writing some perl/python/ruby/whatever to read the json and `insert` into PostgreSQL using the language's DB driver.

Comment: Right. Is there a mechanism to integrate any ETL tool with Postgres?

Comment: "Integrate" how? They're clients, like any other, talking to PostgreSQL over ODBC/JDBC/libpq/whatever.

Comment: @CraigRinger ..Apologies for diverting you from the topic. I have a CSV file . I want to dump it in Postgres. I did the following: create table test (plc text,direction text,speed text,timestamp text,time_id text) COPY test(plc ,direction ,speed ,timestamp,time_id) FROM '/home/shashank/staging/' DELIMITER ',' CSV. I get no errors, but when I do select * from test , I get no results. Please suggest.

Comment: Huh, that has nothing to do with this question. New question? "Ask a question" button.

Comment: I think instead of suggesting me.. you could have annswered here.

Comment: I could've, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. It's designed so that *other people can learn from questions and answers later*, but having a structured format that makes information discoverable and searchable. If you want a free discussion forum, there are lots of them elsewhere. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help. If you have a new question, post a new question. It's still not at all clear what you actually want in this one, anyway.